# Put a margin to the floated div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello i want to put a space between the calendar div and text. I tried to put `margin-left` on the text but it's not working and `margin-right` to the calendar div but as expected it's not working. Can someone give me ideas? Help me please. I think the cause of the problem is the `float:left;` to the div calendar.

Here is the picture
[image]

here is my html code for the sidebar

```
 <div class="fix sidebar floatright">
   <div class="fix single_sidebar">
     <div class="events">
       <h2>Upcoming events</h2>
       <hr class="carved">
       <div class="fix single_popular">
         <div class="date">
           <span class="month">August</span>
           <h1 class="day">28</h1>
         </div>
         <h2>Vestibum Malesuada Etiam Magna</h2>
         <p>7:00 AM - 8:00 PM</p>
       </div>
       <hr>
       <div class="fix single_popular">
         <div class="date">
           <span class="month">August</span>
           <h1 class="day">28</h1>
         </div>
         <h2>Vestibum Malesuada Etiam Magna</h2>
         <p>7:00 AM - 8:00 PM</p>
       </div>
       <hr>
       <div class="fix single_popular">
         <div class="date">
           <span class="month">August</span>
           <h1 class="day">28</h1>
         </div>
         <h2>Vestibum Malesuada Etiam Magna</h2>
         <p>7:00 AM - 8:00 PM</p>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

here is my css for the sidebar and also the calendar div.

```
hr.carved {
  clear: both;
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  border: none;
  background: #ddd;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(
      linear,
      left top,
      left bottom,
      color-stop(0.5, rgb(126,27,18)),
      color-stop(0.5, rgb(211,45,31))
  );
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
      center top,
      rgb(126,27,18) 50%,
      rgb(211,45,31) 50%
  );
}

a {
  color:#000;
  text-decoration:none
}
a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active {
  text-decoration:none;
  outline:none;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
  font-weight:normal;
  margin:0 0 15px;
}
.floatright {
  float: right;
}
.floatleft {
  float: left;
}
.fix {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.sidebar {
  background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
  border:1px solid #a92419;
  padding:19px;
  width: 250px;
}
.single_sidebar_ {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  color:#898989;
}
.single_sidebar input {
  width: 90%;
}
.events > h2,.single_sidebar > h2 {
  color:#a92419;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 22px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.single_sidebar a {
  display: block;
  color: #898989;
}
.single_sidebar a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.single_popular {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.single_popular img {
  margin-right: 8px;
}
.single_popular h2 {
  color:#898989;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.single_popular p {
  color: #717171;
  font-size:11px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.date {
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
.date .month {
  background: #a92419;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #a92419;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 0 #a92419;
}

.date .day {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color:#a92419;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ccc;
  position: relative;
}

.date .day::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 95%;
  width: 96%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 2%;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ccc;
}

.date .day::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  left: 5%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.events img{
  height: 80px;
  width: 140px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use margin-right

```
.date
    {
    margin-right:10px;
    }
```

Comment: It worked ma'am! Thank you very much. But i remeber putting margin-right as i mentioned to my question.  Weird.

Answer (score 2):

replace with below css will solve issue. just i have added margin-right 10px

```
   .date {
      display: block;
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      margin: 0 10px 20px 0;
      background: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
      position: relative;
      float: left;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.date { margin-right: 10px }`

```css
hr.carved {
  clear: both;
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  border: none;
  background: #ddd;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.5, rgb(126, 27, 18)), color-stop(0.5, rgb(211, 45, 31)));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( center top, rgb(126, 27, 18) 50%, rgb(211, 45, 31) 50%);
}

a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none
}

a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
}

.floatright {
  float: right;
}

.floatleft {
  float: left;
}

.fix {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #a92419;
  padding: 19px;
  width: 250px;
}

.single_sidebar_ {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  color: #898989;
}

.single_sidebar input {
  width: 90%;
}

.events > h2,
.single_sidebar > h2 {
  color: #a92419;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 22px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.single_sidebar a {
  display: block;
  color: #898989;
}

.single_sidebar a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.single_popular {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.single_popular img {
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.single_popular h2 {
  color: #898989;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.single_popular p {
  color: #717171;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.date {
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.date .month {
  background: #a92419;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #a92419;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 0 #a92419;
}

.date .day {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #a92419;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ccc;
  position: relative;
}

.date .day::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 95%;
  width: 96%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 2%;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ccc;
}

.date .day::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  left: 5%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.events img {
  height: 80px;
  width: 140px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fix sidebar floatright">
  <div class="fix single_sidebar">
    <div class="events">
      <h2>Upcoming events</h2>
      <hr class="carved">
      <div class="fix single_popular">
        <div class="date">
          <span class="month">August</span>
          <h1 class="day">28</h1>
        </div>
        <h2>Vestibum Malesuada Etiam Magna</h2>
        <p>7:00 AM - 8:00 PM</p>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="fix single_popular">
        <div class="date">
          <span class="month">August</span>
          <h1 class="day">28</h1>
        </div>
        <h2>Vestibum Malesuada Etiam Magna</h2>
        <p>7:00 AM - 8:00 PM</p>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="fix single_popular">
        <div class="date">
          <span class="month">August</span>
          <h1 class="day">28</h1>
        </div>
        <h2>Vestibum Malesuada Etiam Magna</h2>
        <p>7:00 AM - 8:00 PM</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```